# How to order joined results in Phalcon Framework

Tags: php, database, phalcon

Let's pretend I'm working on a magazine, where a Category (like "sport", "art" an so on) can contain several Articles. Therefore I want to extract all articles for a specific category. In Phalcon I usually do:

```
$category = \Models\Category::findFirst(array(
    'conditions' => 'id = ?1',
    'bind'       => array(1 => $id)
));
```

Then:

```
foreach ($category->Article as $article) {
    // do something with $article
}
```

It works great, but I would like to sort those Articles - say - date wise, ascending. How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `get` prefix in your `for..loop` statement, so your code should like this :

```
foreach ($category->getArticle(array('order' => 'date DESC')) as $article) {
    // do something with $article
}
```

The main [Docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#taking-advantage-of-relationships) explains more examples.
Try it & get your results.

Comment: Good point. Actually I had a nasty error using the "bare" field 'date': `Can't obtain model's source from models list: 'CMS\Models\Article'`. I ended up doing something like `foreach ($category->getArticle(array('order' => '[\CMS\Models\Article].date DESC'))` (notice the square brackets), as suggested [here](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/7585/get-all-results-from-3rd-level-related-tables).

Comment: OK,  i think because of you using namespaces in your models you should prefer the namespace before your field name.

Answer (score 3):

M2sh answer is all important and actual, I just will post a secondary way, just using model designed for articles:

```
$page = 5; // eg. 5th page of results
$limit = 100; // eg. 100 results per page

$articles = \Models\Articles::find(array(
    'conditions' => 'category_id = :cid:',
    'bind' => array(
        'cid' => $id
    ),
    'order' => 'date DESC, id DESC',
    'limit' => $limit,
    'offset' => $page * $limit
));
```

It's possible to use such set of parameters in M2sh way aswell.

Answer (score 1):

One more for completeness.  I will borrow from yergo to illustrate the differences:

```
$page = 5;
$limit = 100;

$articles = \Models\Articles::query()
    ->where('category_id= :cid:', array('cid' => $id)
    ->orderBy('date DESC, id DESC')
    ->limit($limit)
    ->offset($page * $limit)
    ->query();
```

Comment: You can also use `bind` which sometimes makes it more clear if you have to bind a lot of different variables to the query.

Comment: Or you can pass bind parameters array into `query()` iirc. Queries built via [queryBuilder](https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/phql.html) are handled this way, important to learn for some more complex queries.